# No sound after upgrade from Windows Vista -> 8.1 on Dell Inspiron 1420

Tags: audio, dell-inspiron, windows-8-upgrade

I have recently upgraded a working Dell Inspiron 1420 laptop with Windows Vista to Windows 8 and subsequently Windows 8.1 (all 32-bit).

Sound was working prior to the upgrade.  After the upgrade, sound no longer works.  The symptoms are as follows:

- No sound through speakers or headphones
- On the "volume" button on the taskbar, there are no devices to adjust.
- The Device Manager as devices as "speaker" and "spdif"
- "Playback devices" lists no usable devices (even when requesting disabled or missing devices)

The [official driver page](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/Product/inspiron-1420) lists drivers for 32-bit Vista.  Attempting to install the appropriate device (SIGMATEL STAC 92XX C-Major HD Audio, v.6.10.0.5614, A03) yields the following error, even when attempting to run in Vista compatibility mode:

- "Device object not found"

Looking at the [FAQ](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19510764.aspx) has some suggestions, but:

- The [uninstall/reinstall procedure](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19352371.aspx#1.%20Basic) yields no results
- The [IDT Driver Option](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19352371.aspx#8.%20You%20Installed%207) says it cannot continue until the SigmaTel driver is uninstalled  (which is not listed anywhere!).

I'm running out of options. Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

By luck, I have come across a solution, but I do not fully understand why it works.  The only clue I have is that the "device object missing" refers to the installer not being able to find any sound card at all (?).

Anyway, I downloaded and installed the a [Realtek R2.73 driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) despite not having this hardware on the system.

After a reboot, this seemed to create the (non-working) audio devices when looking at "Sound -> Playback devices".

Then, installing the official [SigmaTel for Vista 32-bit](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/Product/inspiron-1420) drivers for the laptop installed as normal.

Thus, I have a solution, but I would appreciate comments as to why this worked....

Comment: Your Realtek R2.73 link is broken. It says, "Object moved to here", but it turns out to be a link loop. Do you have an alternate verified download location for that driver?